# Made a mistake reporting total income on T1 tax forms

Tags: taxes, income-tax, canada, canada-revenue-agency

This is a bit embarrassing but apparently, I made a mistake on my income tax return. In particular, the "total income field". In my first tax return(2017), I thought this was "monthly income", but prepping my tax return for 2018, I realize the total income was referring to "total anual income". It sounds stupid how I could make a mistake, I know!

On the other hand, during 2017 - 2018, I paid taxes accordingly to on a month to month basis so I would not be owning any money.

I use simplex to file my tax returns but because of the mistake I made in the first year, entering in my actual total income, it's stated I owe several thousand dollars.

The question is, is there any legal overhead/extra work I need to look into after submitting my tax return or because I already paid X amount of taxes owing, will it resolve its self? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

I am sort of brand new to the whole "taxes"...